# adding gaussian noise to image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to add gaussian noise to some images using the following code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob 
mean = 0
var = 10
sigma = var ** 0.5
gaussian = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (224, 224)) 



for image in glob.glob('/home/aub/myflower/flower_photos/dandelion/*.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    noisy_image = np.zeros(img.shape, np.float32)

    if len(img.shape) == 2:
        noisy_image = img + gaussian
    else:
        noisy_image[:, :, 0] = img[:, :, 0] + gaussian
        noisy_image[:, :, 1] = img[:, :, 1] + gaussian
        noisy_image[:, :, 2] = img[:, :, 2] + gaussian

        cv2.normalize(noisy_image, noisy_image, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=-1)
noisy_image = noisy_image.astype(np.uint8)

       cv2.imshow("img", img)
       cv2.imshow("gaussian", gaussian)
       cv2.imshow("noisy", noisy_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but it doesn't work and it gives me the following error

> noisy_image[:, :, 0] = img[:, :, 0] + gaussian ValueError: operands
>   could not be broadcast together with shapes (315,500) (224,224)

Kindly review and give feedback.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like your image shape is `(315,500)`, while the shape of `gaussian` is `(224,224)`. Try changing your gaussian initialization to

```
gaussian = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (img.shape[0],img.shape[1]))
```

By the way:
You can replace these lines

```
noisy_image[:, :, 0] = img[:, :, 0] + gaussian
noisy_image[:, :, 1] = img[:, :, 1] + gaussian
noisy_image[:, :, 2] = img[:, :, 2] + gaussian
```

with

```
noisy_image = img + gaussian
```

which will have the same effect: adding `gaussian` to each channel.

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback, i changed the lines and the also changed the shape to (img.shape[0],img.shape[1]) and it works now, thank you

Comment: You are welcome and you are right, using `(img.shape[0],img.shape[1])` is far better, I will add that to my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work if the pixel you're noising is [255,255,255] and the noise you're adding is positive

Comment: Adding np.clip(img, 0, 255) avoids getting values outside 8 bits range.